# Is this induced map non-trivial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphisms of varieties over $k$ (i.e. $X$ and $Y$ are integral separated $k$-schemes of finite type). Then $f$ induces a $k$-homomorphism between function fields $g:K(Y) \to K(X)$.

My question is whether or not $f$ being surjective implies that the homomorphism $g$ is nonzero.

Comment: What do you mean by $g$ nontrivial? Like $g$ is nonzero? Or do you mean $g$ is not the identity?

Comment: @K02 I mean that $g$ is nonzero.

Comment: It takes 1 to 1, hence nonzero.

Comment: @Sasha could you please elaborate on where exactly the surjectivity of $f$ is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard convention in algebraic geometry is that all rings are commutative and unital and all ring homomorphisms are unital, i.e. if $f:A\to B$ is a map of rings then $f(1_A)=1_B$. Bearing that in mind, we see that all morphisms of fields are injective, and there are pairs of fields where there are no maps from one to the other - for instance, there is no map $\Bbb F_4\to \Bbb F_2$ since any such map cannot be injective for cardinality reasons. (There are other examples, clearly.)

With these conventions fixed, a morphism of varieties $f$ does not always induce a morphism of function fields. For instance, any map $\Bbb A^n\to\Bbb A^{n+m}$ for $m>0$ cannot have an induced map on function fields, since a map of fields is injective and transcendence degree adds over field extensions - a morphism of function fields corresponding to a morphism of varieties $\Bbb A^n\to\Bbb A^{n+m}$ would give a tower of field extensions $k\subset k(t_1,\cdots,t_{n+m}) \subset k(t_1,\cdots,t_n)$, which is impossible as $n+m\not\leq n$.

In order to get an induced map on function fields of varieties, one requires that the morphism is **dominant**, or has dense image. In particular, a surjective map is dominant, so one gets an induced map of function fields. Depending on your level of technology, there are several ways to do this - if you're coming from the scheme-theoretic viewpoint as suggested by your question, the map on function fields associated to a dominant morphism $f:X\to Y$ is the induced map $\mathcal{O}_{Y,\eta_Y}\to\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta_X}$ where $\eta_X$ and $\eta_Y$ are the generic points of $X$ and $Y$. (There's some content here - you need to show that $\eta_X\mapsto \eta_Y$, verify that these stalks are fields, etc. Once you do that, you have a ring homomorphism of fields, which by the above is injective.)